# Windows Batch Script for getting disk space details

Tags: windows, batch

I need to get the mail alert for disk space details. I have found this script in our forum. When I run this script in command prompt, it generates the output as mentioned below.  But when I run this by saving it as a batch file, it doesn't work.

Can any one help me how to make this as a batch file or any other method to get the disk space details using batch file, so that I could schedule in Task Scheduler.

#### Script

> (for /f "tokens=1-3" %a in ('WMIC LOGICALDISK GET FreeSpace^,Name^,Size ^|FINDSTR /I /V "Name"') do @echo wsh.echo "%b" ^& " free=" ^& FormatNumber^(cdbl^(%a^)/1024/1024/1024, 2^)^& " GB"^& " size=" ^& FormatNumber^(cdbl^(%c^)/1024/1024/1024, 2^)^& " GB" > %temp%\tmp.vbs & @if not "%c"=="" @echo( & @cscript //nologo %temp%\tmp.vbs & del %temp%\tmp.vbs) > E:\monitoring_scripts\log\Disk_status.txt

#### Output

> C: free=79,11 GiB size=111,45 GiB
>   D: free=929,47 GiB size=931,51 GiB

Answer (score 2):

Double the `%` sign denoting loop control variables: `%a` to `%%a`, `%b` to `%%b` and so on:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions
(for /f "tokens=1-3" %%a in ('
  WMIC LOGICALDISK GET FreeSpace^,Name^,Size ^|FINDSTR /I /V "Name"
  ') do (
    echo wsh.echo "%%b" ^& " free=" ^& FormatNumber^(cdbl^(%%a^)/1024/1024/1024, 2^)^& " GB"^& " size=" ^& FormatNumber^(cdbl^(%%c^)/1024/1024/1024, 2^)^& " GB" > "%temp%\tmp.vbs"
    if not "%%c"=="" (
      echo( 
      cscript //nologo "%temp%\tmp.vbs"
      del "%temp%\tmp.vbs"
    )
  )
) > E:\monitoring_scripts\log\Disk_status.txt
```

or, with less disk writes to the `%temp%` folder and with the only `cscript` call:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions
(for /f "tokens=1-3" %%a in ('
  WMIC LOGICALDISK GET FreeSpace^,Name^,Size ^|FINDSTR /I /V "Name"
  ') do (
    if not "%%c"=="" (
      echo wsh.echo vbNewLine ^& "%%b" ^& " free=" ^& FormatNumber^(cdbl^(%%a^)/1024/1024/1024, 2^)^& " GB"^& " size=" ^& FormatNumber^(cdbl^(%%c^)/1024/1024/1024, 2^)^& " GB"
    )
  )
) > "%temp%\tmp.vbs"
cscript //nologo "%temp%\tmp.vbs" > E:\monitoring_scripts\log\Disk_status.txt
del "%temp%\tmp.vbs"
```

Resources (further reading): [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)

Comment: Wow ! ! Awesome...  Thank you so much Josef.  It works awesome.

Comment: I need to trigger an alert by if condition like if the disk gets filled up more than 90%, then I must do an alert mail. I can work with the Mailing process. Kindly suggest how to do the if loop on disk get filled more than 90%.

Comment: @DhanuDBA `^& " GB percent=" ^& Round^(100 *cdbl^(%%a^) / cdbl^(%%c^), 0^)` instead of _last_ `^& " GB"` and then parse output using `for /F "usebackq tokens=3 delims==" %%G in ("Disk_status.txt") do if %%G LEQ 10 echo trigger alert` (sorry, not tested...). Change to `tokens=1,?` and `delims=:=` to get disk letter as well (use appropriate number instead of `?`).

Comment: Hi Josef,  I have tried like this. am I doing it write.                                                
(for /F "usebackq tokens=3 delims==" %%G in ('
  WMIC LOGICALDISK GET FreeSpace^,Name^,Size ^|FINDSTR /I /V "Name" ') do (echo wsh.echo "%%b" ^& " free=" ^& FormatNumber^(cdbl^(%%a^)/1024/1024/1024, 2^)^& " GB"^& " size=" ^& FormatNumber^(cdbl^(%%c^)/1024/1024/1024, 2^)^& " GB percent=" ^& Round^(100 *cdbl^(%%a^) / cdbl^(%%c^), 0^) > "%temp%\tmp.vbs"
    if %%G LEQ 10(echo( cscript //nologo "%temp%\tmp.vbs"
      del "%temp%\tmp.vbs"))) > D:\moitor_scripts\log\Disk_space.txt